# .NET Core Class Library with EF 7: type Func<,> is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a .NET Core Class Library for my database context. This is how my project.json looks like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "MyProject.EventStore.EF Class Library",
  "authors": [ "me" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write something like this:

```
context.SnapShots.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EventProviderId == snapShot.EventProviderId);
```

and I'm getting an error for `FirstOrDefault` invocation:

> Error CS0012  The type 'Func<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. MyProject.EventStore.EF..NET
>   Framework 4.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add that in frameworkAssemblies like this:

```
"frameworks": {
"net451": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0"

    }
}
```